# How to show an alert if submitting form was successful and how to validate the user inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have created a form and the PHP code for it to send an e-mail but I can't seem to implement some kind of a seamless alert without a page refresh when submitting the form. I need some kind of text green/red to appear somewhere below the button. I also need to validate proper input of email in the email input box. And also need to protect this site from spam bots emailing, right now i just have HTML and PHP, my PHP:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    $to = $_POST['emailTo'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['fullName'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $mailsubject = "Online Contact Form Inquery";

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><body>";
    $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
    $body .= "<tbody>";
    
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Dear Gumcash Employee,</strong></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>You Received an e-mail from the online website, see details below:</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Comment:</strong> {$comment}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Thank you</td></tr>";
    
    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";
    
    $send = mail($to, $mailsubject, $body, $headers);
    header('Location:contact.html');
    die();
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<form action="contact_process.php" method="POST" id="form">
               <div class="contact-form">
                  <div class="col-md-6 form-field input-halfrght">
                     <input name="fullName" id="fullName"type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Full Name*" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 form-field input-halflft">
                     <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Email*" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 form-field">
                     <select id="emailTo" name="emailTo" type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Send To*" required>
                        <option value="e_cashdan@cashdan.com">Eric Cashdan</option>
                        <option value="r_gumersell@gumcash.com">Rich Gummersell</option>
                        <option value="g_garibaldi@gumcash.com">Gino Garibaldi</option>
                        <option value="d_macgillivray@gumcash.com">Don Macgillivray</option>
                        <option value="k_ohrnberger@gumcash.com">Kevin Ohrnberger</option>
                        <option value="d_samuylov@gumcash.com">Dmitri Samuylov</option>
                        <option value="m_caputo@gumcash.com">Mike Caputo</option>
                        <option value="f_meza">Frank Meza</option>
                        <option value="j_javett@gumcash.com">Joann Javett</option>
                        <option value="c_baum@gumcash.com">Colleen Baum</option>
                        <option value="d_payne@gumcash.com">Devin Arciprete</option>
                        <option value="m_roche">Melissa Roche</option>
                        <option value="a_collora@gumcash.com">Amy Collora</option>
                        <option value="c_aguilar@gumcash.com">Carlos Aguilar</option>
                        <option value="accounting@gumcash.com">Accounting</option>
                        <option value="quotations@gumcash.com">Quote</option>
                        <option value="orders@gumcash.com">Orders</option>
                        <option value="office@lovolta.com">Eugene TESTING</option>

                        </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 form-field">
                     <textarea name="comment" cols="1" rows="2" class="form-comment" placeholder="Comment*"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-field no-margin">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-field no-margin">
                     
                     <input name="submit" type="submit" class="form-submit-btn" value="Submit Now">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
```

Trying to validate the email input, and the drop down select selects the email I want to submit this form TO. Special type of scenario. Any help would be appreciate to validate, send confirmation and block bots. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*" Without refreshing the page "* - PHP is a server-side language: it fetches and executes once and forgets its state; you need to send a request to execute the necessary files each time.

With that in mind, thankfully, we have JavaScript. You can create an AJAX request to your URI with your post data on the client-side and then receive the response.

```
fetch('contact_process.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body:   new URLSearchParams(new FormData(document.getElementById('form')))
})
.then(response => {
    return response.json()
})
.then(response => {
    // todo: add your alerts
});
```

**Note:** Your `contact_process.php` page should return a `json_encode()` response. Likewise, the correct content type should be returned.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

die(json_encode(array(
    'status'   => true,
    'message'  => 'Your custom message based on the outcome',
)));
```

You can then access them through the JavaScript `response` variable like:

```
.then(response => {
    if(response.status) {
        // show your response.message in green
        return;
    }

    // show your response.message in red

});
```

To implement this, you need to alter your current solution.

1. Remove the `form` tags
2. Alter your `input` tag for your button to type `button` instead of `submit`
3. Give the button an ID like `id='submit-btn'`
4. Add an event listener to it

---

```
document.getElementById('submit-btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // fetch in here
});
```

Comment: Either i'm doing something wrong or Im not sure how to puzzle this together or show my messages.. Everything works, when i click submit i just get a blank white html page with "{"status":true,"message":"Your custom message based on the outcome"}" message then i get the email. Please elaborate

Comment: If you could just edit my code would be so helpful , appreciate it

Comment: I updated my question for you @YevgeniyYerokhin

Comment: you have 3 pieces of code, which ones go where? can you create a sample alert

Comment: I think your trouble here is that you do not understand the technology stack at hand and thus would highly advise you to sought a professional developer to do this. Your PHP goes at the end of your file, prior to your already in use `die()`. Your JavaScript then goes into your front-end HTML in a `<script>` tag. It is no where near complete either, you have to implement the alert how you want it, or look to hire someone.